# JMS template bad performance 224ms to post a message

Tags: spring, spring-jms

Spring JMStemplate takes around 200 to 240 ms to post a message even if a JNDI connection factory is used.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm  http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">




    <beans:bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" 
           class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="jndiName" value="jms/TesService"/>
        <beans:property name="resourceRef" value="false"/>
        <beans:property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
        <beans:property name="cache" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <jms:listener-container acknowledge="transacted" cache="session" connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
        concurrency="1" container-type="default"
        container-class="org.kp.oppr.ancillary.jms.container.TesMessageListenerContainer">
        <jms:listener id="QL.TEST.84" destination="QL.TEST.OUTPUT.84" ref="ancillaryMessageListener" method="onMessage" />
        <jms:listener id="QL.TEST.85" destination="QL.TEST.OUTPUT.85" ref="ancillaryMessageListener" method="onMessage" />
    </jms:listener-container>


    <beans:bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <beans:property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="pubSubDomain" value="false" />
        <beans:property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- JMS Beans -->
    <beans:bean id="jmsMessageProducer" class="org.kp.oppr.test.helpers.JmsMessageProducer">
    <beans:property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="testMessageListener" class="org.kp.oppr.test.jms.listener.TestMessageListener" scope="prototype">
    <beans:property name="retryDelay" value="${retry.delay}"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="maxRetry" value="${retry.allowed}"></beans:property>


    </beans:bean>
```

and the class to post the message is

```
  package org.test.helpers;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator;

import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue;

public class JmsMessageProducer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsMessageProducer.class);
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    private MQQueue queue;


    public MQQueue getQueue() {
        return queue;
    }

    public void setQueue(MQQueue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }



    /**
     *
     */
    public void sendMessage(final String message, final String queueName) throws JMSException {

        MQQueue queue = new MQQueue(queueName);
        queue.setTargetClient(1);       


        long queueStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        jmsTemplate.send(queue, new MessageCreator() {
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(message);
                //message.setIntProperty(MESSAGE_COUNT, index);

                return textMessage;
            }
        });

        if(LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.info("Queue put time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - queueStartTime) + " queue: " + queue.getQueueName());
            LOGGER.info("Sent message to queue: " + queue.getQueueName() + " message: " + message);
        }

    }

    public JmsTemplate getJmsTemplate() {
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }
}



</beans:beans>
```

`

The queue put time is coming as 220ms. The JNDI connection factory is on Web sphere 8.5... Ideally it should not be more than 30ms..

Do let me know if I am missing something in my configuration files

Answer (score 0):

Use caching currently for each send operation a `Connection` is retrieved, which is used to create a `Session` which is used to create a `Producer`. This is all overhead and delaying (probably most time is wasted creating a `Session`.

You can configure a [`CachingConnectionFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.html) or when you only want a single connection use a [`SingleConnectionFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/SingleConnectionFactory.html). For more information take a look at [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-connections).

```
<beans:bean id="cachingConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <beans:property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <beans:property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="pubSubDomain" value="false" />
    <beans:property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingConnectionFactory"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Looking at your JNDI lookup

```
<beans:bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" 
       class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="jndiName" value="jms/TesService"/>
    <beans:property name="resourceRef" value="false"/>
    <beans:property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <beans:property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <beans:property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"/>
</beans:bean>
```

First I would suggest use the jee namespace to do the lookup and don't set the `lookupOnStartup` to `false`. The latter will delay the first receive/send of the message as the whole JNDI lookup still has to take place.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="jmsConnectionFactory" jndi-name="jms/TesService" proxy-interface="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" />
```

Also in  your code you don't need the `MessageCreator` the JmsTemplate by default will create a `TextMessage` for a `String` payload.

```
public void sendMessage(final String message, final String queueName) throws JMSException {
        MQQueue queue = new MQQueue(queueName);
        queue.setTargetClient(1);       

        long queueStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, message);

        if(LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.info("Queue put time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - queueStartTime) + " queue: " + queue.getQueueName());
            LOGGER.info("Sent message to queue: " + queue.getQueueName() + " message: " + message);
        }
}
```

If you want to add additional headers or properties to the `javax.jms.Message` use a `MessagePostProcessor` instead.

Comment: I get the following error on Configuring cachingConnectionFactory{Method setExceptionListener not permitted; nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Method setExceptionListener not permitted
org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: Method setExceptionListener not permitted; nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Method setExceptionListener not permitted
 at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:279) ~[spring-jms-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]}

Comment: Additionally there is no method in JMSTemplate for jmsTemplate.send(queue, message);

Comment: My bad, should have been `convertAndSend`. Modified answer. Please update your question to include the full stacktrace. You should only use the `cachingConnectionFactory` for the `JmsTemplate` not the listener container.